# python qt float precision from boost-python submodule

Tags: python, c++, boost, pyqt4, precision

I have made a cpp submodule with boost-python for my PyQt program that among others extracts some data from a zip data file.

It works fine when testing it in python:

```
import BPcmods
BPzip = BPcmods.BPzip()
BPzip.open("diagnostics/p25-dev.zip")
l=BPzip.getPfilenames()
t=BPzip.getTempArray([l[1][4],l[1][3]],40.)
print(t[11][:10])

>> [40.1, 40.44, 40.78, 41.11, 41.44, 41.77, 41.77, 42.09, 42.41, 42.73]
```

if I put the same code in the start of my **main** part, it also gives the same data, but if I put the code right after I call

```
main.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

It suddenly yields:

```
[40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 42.0, 42.0, 42.0]
```

Why?? what happened? The numbers are still floats, but suddenly they have been rounded to nearest integer?!?

Comment: Developed code is on Ubuntu 16.04 using python-pyside (python 2.7 and Qt4), but I just tried with pyQt4 qnd PyQt5 packages as well and also with my module compiled for python 3.5. All the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Well it was related to using std::stod to convert my strings of data from my datafile to doubles. I don't know why, but changing to:

```
boost::algorithm::trim(s);
double val = boost::lexical_cast<double>(s);
```

made it work as it was supposed to, also in pyqt.